# connect php to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to connect an html form to a mysql database through php.  This is my code for the php script:

```
include_once('db_connect.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {


$lokotitle=$_POST['lokotitle'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$showyourname=$_POST['showyourname'];
$yourname=$_POST['yourname'];
$lat=$_POST['lat'];
$lng=$_POST['lng'];


// Will add form validation here 


if ($errorMessage != "" ) {
    echo "<p class='message'>" .$errorMessage. "</p>" ;
}

else{
    //Inserting record in table using INSERT query
    $insqDbtb="INSERT INTO `new_loko`.`web_form`
    (`lokotitle`, `description`, `category`, `showyourname`, `yourname`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('$lokotitle', '$description', '$category', '$showyourname', '$yourname', '$lat', '$lng')";
    mysqli_query($link,$insqDbtb) or die(mysqli_error($link));


    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.location = "submit_success.php";</script> 
    <?php


    }
}
```

My include_once('db_connect.php') is properly working, but the php simply runs this part, checks that the connection is working, which it is, and then stops without actually uploading the data to the database.  I can't figure out what's wrong with the code.  Also, I had this working earlier and am not sure why it no longer is.

Thanks in advance for the much needed help.

Comment: what is $errorMessage ?, first remove redirection then check it is inserting or not. before inserting data it might redirecting your page

Comment: Just an empty variable that I will use for validation

Comment: What error you get from MySQL?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: It is currently empty so I don't see why it wouldnt just skip the if statement and go to the else.

Comment: There is no error just nothing happens

Comment: I've been using this to check if it is properly working:  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.location = "submit_success.php";</script> 
    <?php         This only runs when I put it above the second if statement.

Comment: remove  <code> <script type="text/javascript">window.location = "submit_success.php";</script> <code> then check it once

Comment: Still doesn't run the insertion into the db

Comment: try this, just replace " ` " to " ' " in INSERT query.

Comment: Make sure you connected with the server and database correctly and then try

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Switching the apostrophes didn't change anything, and I have checked and the db seems to be connected correctly.  Here is the db_connect code:  Im using MAMP.                                                $user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'new_loko';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 8889;

$link = mysqli_init();
$success = mysqli_real_connect(
   $link, 
   $host, 
   $user, 
   $password, 
   $db,
   $port
);


echo 'Success... ';

Comment: Tadman what should I do instead?

Comment: My error is :           Warning: mysqli_query(): invalid object or resource mysqli in /Users/.../Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/web_projects/coming_soon/handleform/sendformdata.p‌​hp on line 33 –

Comment: @pcris check with your post data. whether it is a valid details is passing. Rather you declare a value directly for that variables and try whether is inserting or not

Comment: Is it correct to use collation utf8_unicode_ci in phpmyadmin?

Comment: yes it allow utf8 fonts and symbols

Comment: You should use objects for MySQL databases

Answer (score 0):

declare your `$errorMessage`  with empty then change value as per validations.

```
   <?php

    include_once('db_connect.php');

    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {


    $lokotitle=$_POST['lokotitle'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $showyourname=$_POST['showyourname'];
    $yourname=$_POST['yourname'];
    $lat=$_POST['lat'];
    $lng=$_POST['lng'];

    $errorMessage="";
    /* some validation

    if(validation)
      $errorMessage="some message";
     -------------------
     -------------------
     -------------------
     // Will add form validation here
     */

    if ($errorMessage != "" ) {
        echo "<p class='message'>" .$errorMessage. "</p>" ;
    }

    else{
        //Inserting record in table using INSERT query
        $insqDbtb="INSERT INTO `new_loko`.`web_form`
        (`lokotitle`, `description`, `category`, `showyourname`, `yourname`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('$lokotitle', '$description', '$category', '$showyourname', '$yourname', '$lat', '$lng')";
        mysqli_query($link,$insqDbtb) or die(mysqli_error($link));


        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">window.location = "submit_success.php";</script>
        <?php


        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Yes I added the $errorMessage and it still doesnt seem to run everything.

Comment: can you please remove your   <script type="text/javascript">window.location = "submit_success.php";</script> , and execute. then update here what output your getting....

Comment: it seems problem with your $link object. can you please check it once

Comment: All my $link item is is this: $link = mysqli_init();

Comment: Thus I'm not sure what is wrong with $link.  It says something is wrong with mysqli_query($link,$insqDbtb), not sure what though.

Comment: i hope $link is having connection object,$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db"); if not , change and execute once

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have some extra `s in your call database.table call

yours

```
 $insqDbtb="INSERT INTO `new_loko`.`web_form`
 (`lokotitle`, `description`, `category`, `showyourname`, `yourname`,             `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('$lokotitle', '$description', '$category', '$showyourname',     '$yourname', '$lat', '$lng')";
      mysqli_query($link,$insqDbtb) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

try this:

```
 $insqDbtb="INSERT INTO `new_loko.web_form`
    (`lokotitle`, `description`, `category`, `showyourname`, `yourname`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('$lokotitle', '$description', '$category', '$showyourname', '$yourname', '$lat', '$lng')";
    mysqli_query($link,$insqDbtb) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```